# Finding the first duplicate in an array

Tags: c#, array, time-limit-exceeded

My code returns the correct answer the first duplicate is 3 (represented as `int f`) . I am struggling finding a more efficient way to find the first duplicate?

My constraints are \$ 1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length \$ .

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] a = {2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2};

    int f = FirstDuplicate(a);

    Console.ReadLine();
   }
public static int FirstDuplicate(int[] a)
{

    int[] answer = new int[2];
    answer[0] = -1;
    answer[1] = a.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i; j < a.Length; j++)
            if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j)
            {
                if (i < answer[1])
                {
                    answer[0] = a[i];
                    answer[1] = j;
                    break;

                }
            }

    return answer[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: If you aren't prevented from using a `HashSet`, I would think it would yield better performance without the need for the inner loop.

Comment: Minor note.  Since the constraint is all numbers must be between 1 and the array length, a value of `0` could also be used to denote no duplicates were found.

Comment: Even after updating the array, `3` would not be the first duplicate.  Wouldn't `2` be the correct answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code not only does not compile but also returns the last and not the first duplicate so it's not really working.

Comment: 3 is the first duplicate because 3 is the first one to have the 2nd number appear in the array. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Please add that requirement information into the question so that there is no confusion.  Please do not change anything else.

Comment: ... how do you explain that here `{ 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4 }` it finds `2` as a frist duplicate and not `3`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a small array or list of a handful of items, this should be very fast.  But is it efficient as you would scale out?  No.

Before getting on to a better way to achieve the it for a larger number of items, let's look at your current code.  You have some checks that aren't needed.

```
if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j)
```

The check of `i != j` is not needed if you were to simply initialize `j` to be `i + 1` as in:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
    if (a[i] == a[j])
```

The check of `if (i < answer[1])` is totally unnecessary.  In fact, `answer` as an array is not needed at all as you do not really do anything meaningful with `answer[1]`.

But having 2 loops is not efficient as the input array could be larger.  As mentioned in a comment, the use of a `HashSet` could be used.  I am changing a few things.

- The method signature is now `IEnumerable<int>` to allow for arrays,
  lists, or any collection of integers.
- I use a HashSet to keep track of items I have already
  encountered.
- The return type is a `Nullable<int>`, also written as `int?`, so that
  if there are no duplicates found a null is returned.

The resulting method also looks cleaner.  Someone looking at this understands more readily what the code is trying to achieve:

```
public static int? FirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> items)
{

    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (int item in items)
    {
        if (set.Contains(item))
        {
            return item;
        }
        set.Add(item);
    }
    return null;
}
```

As shown in @Denis's answer, and echoed by @Corak, is the method could be made slightly faster and shorter by reducing the logic inside the `foreach` loop:

```
if (!set.Add(item))
{
    return item;
}
```

While this again is *slightly* faster, slighter cleaner, and recommended in practice, it still lags well behind @vnp 's array solution.

**UPDATED Worst Case Array**

I composed a worst case array to test of 100000 items where the very last item is the first duplicate of the 2nd to last item.  Your code and mine returned the correct value.

```
public static int[] WorstCaseArray
{
    get
    {
        int[] items = new int[(int)Math.Pow(10, 5)];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = i + 1;
        }
        items[items.Length - 1] = items[items.Length - 2];  
        return items;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2 - Worst Case**

Obviously we should be working with the largest array allowed.

As @PeterCordes states in a comment to @vnp's answer, the list should be randomized.

As @Denis states, the worst case for a `HashSet` would be if the only duplicate was the first and last item.  An *extremely* close second would be if the last and 2nd to last item were the only duplicate.  Note this second worst case for `HashSet` would be the worst case for @vnp's array solution, so I will use it as my worst case.

```
public static int[] WorstCaseArray
{
    get
    {
        // Worst case is largest allowed array ...
        int max = (int)Math.Pow(10, 5);
        int[] items = new int[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = i + 1;
        }
        // ... that is randomly shuffled ...
        Shuffle(items);
        // ... with the only duplicate being the last item matching the 2nd to last!
        items[items.Length - 1] = items[items.Length - 2];   
        return items;
    }
}

private static Random random = new Random();
public static void Shuffle(int[] items)
{
    //Fisher-Yates method to shuffle
    for (int i = items.Length - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.Next(i + 1);
        int temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[randomIndex];
        items[randomIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED Worst Case Timings**:

- Yours: 14.5105877 seconds
- Mine : 00.0065640 seconds
- vnp's: 00.0012733 seconds

**Tiny array with many duplicates**

However, as I said for only a handful of items yours is quite fast.  The problem is - it produces the wrong answer!  Using this array:

```
int[] array =  new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Where the expected answer would be 3, yours returns 6.

- Yours: took 0.0006141 seconds but returned 6 (wrong)
- Mine : took 0.0006162 seconds
- vnp's : 0.0003843 seconds

**Large, Random Array with No Duplicates**

To round out the answer, let's look at the largest allowed array, randomized, but without any duplicates.  Using the shuffle routine from above:

```
public static int[] NoDuplicates()
{
    int[] items = Enumerable.Range(1, (int)Math.Pow(10, 5)).ToArray();
    Shuffle(items);
    return items;
}
```

Timings:

- Yours: 15.1978462 seconds
- Mine  : 00.0055364 seconds
- vnp's : 00.0014876 seconds

**BEST ANSWER**

Also, since you have tagged this question with [time-limit-exceeded], vnp's answer is not just clever, but also the fastest in all tested scendarios, which makes it the best answer (regarding performance).

Comment: It's not wrong result, quote from OP: *1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ **a[i] ≤ a.length***. A very weird condition if you ask me but..

Comment: @Denis I don't think the condition is weird. It is actually a key to the correct solution. Hint: `HashMap` is an overkill.

Comment: @Denis  _1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5_ means the array length must be between 1 and 100K (I use 10K as my worst).  _1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length_ means each number in the list must range between 1 and the array length inclusively.  For my array of { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6 } the first duplicate encountered is 3.  While 6 is a duplicate, it's not the first so it is the wrong result.

Comment: @RickDavin You're right, I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: @RickDavin small note I think you should return -1 instead of `Nullable<int>`, at least that's how OP's code works.

Comment: I just made comment to OP that a `0` could also be used since the numbers must be >= 1.  I chose to use `Nullable<int>` to introduce the OP to alternatives.  If the tester says it must return `-1`, then yes it should be changed.  But for broader knowledge, I like the `int?`.

Comment: @Denis See edit.

Comment: The `Add` method of `HashSet<T>` by itself checks if the set already contains the value to be added and returns `true` if adding the value was successful (the set *didn't* contain the value) or `false` if adding the value was *not* successful (the set already contained the value). So you can omit one unnecessary check in your `FirstDuplicate` method by having it be `foreach (int item in items) { if (!set.Add(item)) { return item; } }`

Comment: @Corak That was already shown in Denis's answer.  I did not change mine so as not to plagiarize from his answer.  I left it to the OP to review all answers and comments to make the best choice later.

Comment: @Corak Brief followup ... it does make the `HashSet` slightly faster but still no where near as fast as vnp's array solution.  Don't want to update all the timings once again, so I am leaving as it was.  In the future, I will remember and use Add instead.

Comment: @RickDavin - Ah, I see. With standard patterns I wouldn't think in terms of plagiarism (citing or giving credit is always an option). -- Just to add: vnps solution is the best if the number of items is known (like it is in this case), while the `HashSet` way is slower but also works with an unknown number of items, like an `IEnumerable<T>` (which is probably the reason it is used in LINQs `Distinct` for example).

Comment: Worse case test over penalizes the double loop.

Answer (score 14):

Elaborating on my rather cryptic comment.

There is no better hash for an integer than an integer itself, which of course degenerates the `HashMap` into an array. The condition

```
1 <= a_i <= a.length
```

puts the bound to the array size.

The key observation is that given a helper array `h` of the same size as `f`, any element of `f`, say `i`, can be sent into the `i`th slot of `h`. If the slot is already occupied by `i`, we have a duplicate. In pseudocode

```
    int h[f.length]{0}
    for item in f:
        if h[i] == i:
            return i
        h[i] = i
```

Note that if we are allowed to mutate `f`, the algorithm can be adapted to work in-place.

**UPDATED C# IMPLEMENTATION (added by Rick Davin)**

```
public static int FirstDuplicateFast(int[] source)
{
    //Constraint: 1 <= source[i] <= source.Length
    int[] map = new int[source.Length];
    foreach (int value in source)
    {
        if (map[value - 1] != 0)
        {
            return value;
        }
        map[value - 1] = value;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As noted in comments, this is 8-10X faster than a `HashSet`.

Comment: These are intriguing observations that work for special cases.  I am curious as to what your approach would be if the array could contain negative values or even 0?

Comment: This doesn't need to be an int array (unlike CountingSort); a boolean array or bitmap of seen / not-seen would be more sensible (smaller cache footprint = faster, down to 1 byte elements then it's a tradeoff between cache hits vs. ALU and RMW cost instead of writes independent of the reads).  The identity function is the simplest integer -> bucket function, @RickDavin, but if your range includes negative numbers or is small but far from zero (e.g. `[10000 .. 10100]`, adding / subtracting a constant works.  e.g. `seen[ i+1000 ] = true`

Comment: This is about 8 - 10 times faster than a `HashSet`.

Comment: @RickDavin: Did you test with the numbers appearing in sequence?  That improves the cache locality of this version vs. in random order, which probably helps a lot (especially for larger inputs, and especially with an `int` instead of `bool` array).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes the test was with ascending sequence.  I tested again using strictly descending values, and the timings were essentially the same.

Comment: @RickDavin: I'm not surprised; hardware prefetch in modern Intel CPUs can track one forward and one backward stream per page (in the L2 streamer).  HW prefetch can be slightly worse for descending access patterns, but there's not much difference, and you're still touching all 16 `int`s in a cache line basically right away, so there's maximum spatial locality.  I assume AMD's HW prefetching is similarly not bad with descending streams.  (I'm assuming you're on an x86 of some kind.)  It would be interesting to shuffle the elements into a random order (omitting the final one, the duplicate).

Comment: I've read this through 10 times and still do not understand how this works/why it is faster. Really want to understand how it works.

Comment: @hellyale - How it works? Imagine a very simple case: `{ 1, 1 }`. We *know* the length of the array is `2` and through the conditions, we *know* that all the values in the array must be between `1` and that length. So now we create another array of the same length. By default all the values of that second array are set to `0`. Now we go through all the items of the first array and for each item we take the *value* of the item and use it as the *index* in the second array. If the second array has nothing yet set and that exact index, we set it to *something*. Here, simply the value again.

Comment: If we see, that the second array has *something* (other than zero) set at that exact index, we *know* we "visited" that index and thus that value already, and so we must have encountered a duplicate value. -- Now why it's faster? I don't know. Array access via index is very *very* fast. Starting address + (index * sizeof(itemtype)); done. Sets should work "similar", but with some overhead, probably for bucket calculation, possible resizing and whatnot.

Answer (score 6):

Performance is not the only important thing about a piece of code. Depending on the nature of the problem you might also need to consider - readability, maintainability and flexibility. I will present you couple of solutions focusing on those different aspects.

### LINQ

You could use LINQ and write it like this:

```
private static int FirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (source.Count(t => t == item) > 1)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you could've returned 0 instead of -1 in case no duplicates are found, it could've been written like this:

```
private static int FirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(item => source.Count(t => t == item) > 1);
}
```

LINQ is usually quite readable and most C# programmers are familiar with its syntax so it's a lot easier to just give it a glance and know what's up.

### HashSet<>

The `HashSet<T>` is very handy when working with unique numbers as it can contain only distinct numbers. It's `bool Add(T item)` method will allow us to quickly check if a value was already added:

```
private static int FirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    var distinctItems = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!distinctItems.Add(item))
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Again, if you could've returned 0 instead of -1 in case no duplicates are found, it could've been written like this:

```
private static int FirstDuplicate<int>(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    var distinctItems = new HashSet<int>();
    return source.FirstOrDefault(item => !distinctItems.Add(item));
}
```

### Your code

It's often times easy to overthink a simple problem, such is your case, you've over-complicated a simple task. You should think through the problem, before writing code. Some people prefer to write first and than improve afterwards; this also works, but it's always good to think a bit about it before-hand. Especially when you're beginner you might often find yourself tunnel-visioned in a specific way of solving the problem once you're done with it; you could avoid that by thinking before-hand as you won't be so attached to specific ideas.

Missing `for` loop indentation is also reducing the readability of your function.

Comment: It's a dubious claim that the `for` loops are for speed.  That is true for a small collection, but starts to be slower as more items are added.

Comment: @RickDavin not necessarily the quantity of the items, but rather their position. And yes it would affect it more or less it's O(n^2) algorithm in the worst case. `HashSet<>` would suffer in case you have the first and last element as duplicates. But yes I agree, there are cases where `HashSet<>` has the upper-hand

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, and it's probably my fault as I was vague I need the first duplicate so if the set is {2,3,4,3,2}. I need it to return 3 because the 2nd three is the first duplicate.  If I'm not mistaken your loop will return a 2 because the first 2 appears first.

Comment: @AndrewMattick you're right I've removed it from the answer. That makes hashset even more lucrative solution. Or vnp's way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code it O(n^2).  This can be done in O(n).

`int j = i` can be int `j = i + 1` and you can skip the `if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j)`

Looks like you are returning the last duplicate - not the first.

Array lookup is very fast but you should capture the value in the outer loop.  See DoubleLoop below.

Array based is much faster than HashSet but if you did not have the condition `1≤a[i]≤a.length` you could not use array.  In the latest version of .NET I think you can pre-allocate the HashSet capacity but Array would probably still be faster.

```
HashSet     time    434  value 1334
Array       time     46  value 1334
Double loop time 15,321  value 1334
```

.

```
public static void TestDup()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int max = 2000;
    int[] array = new int[max];
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        //array[i] = rand.Next(1, max);
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    //array[max - 1] = max - 1; //not fair to double loop 
    array[max / 3] = array[max * 2 / 3];
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int? dup = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        dup = FindFirstDupicateHashSet(array);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"HashSet time {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0")}  value {dup}");
    sw.Restart();
    dup = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        dup = FindFirstDupicateArray(array);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Array time {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0")}  value {dup}");
    sw.Restart();
    dup = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        dup = FindFirstDupicateDoubleLoop(array);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Double loop time {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0")}  value {dup}");
    Debug.WriteLine("done");
}
public static int? FindFirstDupicateHashSet(int[] array)
{
    int len = array.Length;
    HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach(int i in array)
    {
        if(!hs.Add(i))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static int? FindFirstDupicateArray(int[] array)
{
    int[] compute = new int[array.Length];
    foreach(int i in array)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine($"{i} {compute[i-1]}");
        if(compute[i - 1] > 0)  // 0 is default value
        {
            return i;
        }
        compute[i - 1] = 1;
    }
    return null;
}
public static int? FindFirstDupicateDoubleLoop(int[] array)
{
    int len = array.Length;
    int iVal;
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        iVal = array[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (iVal == array[j])
            {
                return iVal;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the down votes.  It is the only answer with test for timing.  People can test in their environment.